# Generic mexopts file for GCC/Clang OSX/Linux [R2014b]

Tags: matlab, gcc, clang, mex

It is a recurrent pain in the ice to set up this blurry `mexopts.sh`... I would just like a generic configuration that works with all combinations of:

- Ubuntu 14+ and OSX 10.10+;
- gcc 4.8+ and clang 3.5+

I don't want any dependence to Xcode for the OSX part, I don't mind editing that file manually to change version numbers occasionally, and I don't care about warnings regarding the GCC version. 
Here is my chaotic mess so far, hopefully with a little help we can finally get something decent:

```
#
# mexopts.sh    Shell script for configuring MEX-file creation script,
#               mex.  These options were tested with the specified compiler.
#
# usage:        Do not call this file directly; it is sourced by the
#               mex shell script.  Modify only if you don't like the
#               defaults after running mex.  No spaces are allowed
#               around the '=' in the variable assignment.
#
# Note: For the version of system compiler supported with this release,
#       refer to the Supported and Compatible Compiler List at:
#       http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release/
#
#
# SELECTION_TAGs occur in template option files and are used by MATLAB
# tools, such as mex and mbuild, to determine the purpose of the contents
# of an option file. These tags are only interpreted when preceded by '#'
# and followed by ':'.
#
#SELECTION_TAG_MEX_OPT: Template Options file for building MEX-files
#
# Copyright 1984-2011 The MathWorks, Inc.
# $Revision: 1.78.4.18 $  $Date: 2012/11/15 06:22:54 $
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
    TMW_ROOT="$MATLAB"
    MFLAGS=''
    if [ "$ENTRYPOINT" = "mexLibrary" ]; then
        MLIBS="-L$TMW_ROOT/bin/$Arch -lmx -lmex -lmat -lmwservices -lut"
    else  
        MLIBS="-L$TMW_ROOT/bin/$Arch -lmx -lmex -lmat"
    fi
    case "$Arch" in
        Undetermined)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Change this line if you need to specify the location of the MATLAB
# root directory.  The script needs to know where to find utility
# routines so that it can determine the architecture; therefore, this
# assignment needs to be done while the architecture is still
# undetermined.
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            MATLAB="$MATLAB"
            ;;
        glnx86)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Error: Did not imbed 'options.sh' code"; exit 1 #imbed options.sh glnx86 12
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ;;
        glnxa64_gcc|glnxa64)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            RPATH="-Wl,-rpath-link,$TMW_ROOT/bin/$Arch"
#
            CC='gcc'
            CFLAGS='-ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE'
            CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fexceptions"
            CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread"
            CLIBS="$RPATH $MLIBS -lm"
            COPTIMFLAGS='-O2 -DNDEBUG'
            CDEBUGFLAGS='-g'
#
            CXX='g++'
            CXXFLAGS='-ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -std=c++0x'
            CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread"
            CXXLIBS="$RPATH $MLIBS -lm"
            CXXOPTIMFLAGS='-O2 -DNDEBUG'
            CXXDEBUGFLAGS='-g'
#
            FC='gfortran'
            FFLAGS='-fexceptions -fbackslash'
            FFLAGS="$FFLAGS -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer"
            FLIBS="$RPATH $MLIBS -lm"
            FOPTIMFLAGS='-O'
            FDEBUGFLAGS='-g'
#
            LD="$COMPILER"
            LDEXTENSION='.mexa64'
            LDFLAGS="-pthread -shared -Wl,--version-script,$TMW_ROOT/extern/lib/$Arch/$MAPFILE -Wl,--no-undefined"
            LDOPTIMFLAGS='-O'
            LDDEBUGFLAGS='-g'
#
            POSTLINK_CMDS=':'
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ;;
        glnxa64_clang)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            RPATH="-Wl,-rpath-link,$TMW_ROOT/bin/$Arch"
#
            CC='clang'
            CFLAGS="-fno-common -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread"
            CLIBS="$MLIBS -lstdc++"
            COPTIMFLAGS='-O2 -DNDEBUG'
            CDEBUGFLAGS='-g'
#
            CXX='clang++'
            CXXFLAGS="-fno-common -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread"
            CXXLIBS="$RPATH $MLIBS -lstdc++"
            CXXOPTIMFLAGS='-O2 -DNDEBUG'
            CXXDEBUGFLAGS='-g'
#
            FC='gfortran'
            FFLAGS='-fexceptions -fbackslash'
            FFLAGS="$FFLAGS -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer"
            FLIBS="$RPATH $MLIBS -lm"
            FOPTIMFLAGS='-O'
            FDEBUGFLAGS='-g'
#
            LD="$COMPILER"
            LDEXTENSION='.mexa64'
            LDFLAGS="-pthread -shared -Wl,--version-script,$TMW_ROOT/extern/lib/$Arch/$MAPFILE -Wl,--no-undefined"
            LDOPTIMFLAGS='-O'
            LDDEBUGFLAGS='-g'
            POSTLINK_CMDS=':'
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ;;
        sol64|mac|maci)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Error: Did not imbed 'options.sh' code"; exit 1 #imbed options.sh sol64 12
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ;;
        maci64_clang|maci64)
# 
            SDKROOT=""
            MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.10'
            ARCHS='x86_64'
            MAC_FLAGS="-arch $ARCHS -mmacosx-version-min=$MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
#
            CC='clang'
            CFLAGS="-fno-common $MAC_FLAGS"
            CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fexceptions"
            CLIBS="$MLIBS -lstdc++"
            COPTIMFLAGS='-O2 -DNDEBUG'
            CDEBUGFLAGS='-g'
#
            CXX='clang++'
            CXXFLAGS="-fno-common -fexceptions $MAC_FLAGS"
            CXXLIBS="$MLIBS -lstdc++"
            CXXOPTIMFLAGS='-O2 -DNDEBUG'
            CXXDEBUGFLAGS='-g'
#
            FC='gfortran'
            FFLAGS='-fexceptions -m64 -fbackslash'
            FC_LIBDIR=`$FC -print-file-name=libgfortran.dylib 2>&1 | sed -n '1s/\/*libgfortran\.dylib//p'`
            FC_LIBDIR2=`$FC -print-file-name=libgfortranbegin.a 2>&1 | sed -n '1s/\/*libgfortranbegin\.a//p'`
            FLIBS="$MLIBS -L$FC_LIBDIR -lgfortran -L$FC_LIBDIR2 -lgfortranbegin"
            FOPTIMFLAGS='-O'
            FDEBUGFLAGS='-g'
#
            LD="$CC"
            LDEXTENSION='.mexmaci64'
            LDFLAGS="-arch $ARCHS -Wl -mmacosx-version-min=$MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
            LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -bundle -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,$TMW_ROOT/extern/lib/$Arch/$MAPFILE"
            LDOPTIMFLAGS='-O'
            LDDEBUGFLAGS='-g'
#
            POSTLINK_CMDS=':'
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ;;
        maci64_gcc) # doesn't work
# 
            SDKROOT=""
            MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.10'
            ARCHS='x86_64'
            MAC_FLAGS="-arch $ARCHS -mmacosx-version-min=$MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
            RPATH="-Wl,$TMW_ROOT/bin/$Arch"
#
            CC='gcc'
            CFLAGS='-ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE'
            CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fexceptions $MAC_FLAGS"
            CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread"
            CLIBS="$RPATH $MLIBS -lm"
            COPTIMFLAGS='-O2 -DNDEBUG'
            CDEBUGFLAGS='-g'
#
            CXX='g++'
            CXXFLAGS="-ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE $MAC_FLAGS"
            CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread"
            CXXLIBS="$RPATH $MLIBS -lm"
            CXXOPTIMFLAGS='-O2 -DNDEBUG'
            CXXDEBUGFLAGS='-g'
#
            FC='gfortran'
            FFLAGS='-fexceptions -fbackslash'
            FFLAGS="$FFLAGS -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer"
            FLIBS="$RPATH $MLIBS -lm"
            FOPTIMFLAGS='-O'
            FDEBUGFLAGS='-g'
#
            LD="$CC"
            LDEXTENSION='.mexmaci64'
            LDFLAGS="$MAC_FLAGS -bundle -Wl,$TMW_ROOT/extern/lib/$Arch/$MAPFILE"
            LDOPTIMFLAGS='-O'
            LDDEBUGFLAGS='-g'
#
            POSTLINK_CMDS=':'
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ;;
    esac
#############################################################################
#
# Architecture independent lines:
#
#     Set and uncomment any lines which will apply to all architectures.
#
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#           CC="$CC"
#           CFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
#           COPTIMFLAGS="$COPTIMFLAGS"
#           CDEBUGFLAGS="$CDEBUGFLAGS"
#           CLIBS="$CLIBS"
#
#           FC="$FC"
#           FFLAGS="$FFLAGS"
#           FOPTIMFLAGS="$FOPTIMFLAGS"
#           FDEBUGFLAGS="$FDEBUGFLAGS"
#           FLIBS="$FLIBS"
#
#           LD="$LD"
#           LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS"
#           LDOPTIMFLAGS="$LDOPTIMFLAGS"
#           LDDEBUGFLAGS="$LDDEBUGFLAGS"
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#############################################################################
```

You can see that I'm trying to get a different section for each combination `arch_compiler`. I can then manually select the compiler I want simply by ORing the `case` choice with the target architecture.

Comment: why can't you grab a mexopt file from a working OS X install and one from linux and merge them?   i did this once for windows and linux for gcc, intel and portland compilers. this method is going to be painful.

Comment: @GAlexander Yep, that could be a solution but don't all OSX install use Xcode by default in their `mexopts`? Otherwise I'm happy to contribute the default mexopts for Linux+gcc and OSX+clang. I think my Linux+clang section works too, so I really just need the OSX+gcc one :/

Comment: No, some people don't have Xcode installed so matlab provides a lame default C compiler.   With Xcode or the command line tools, you have to jump through hoops to get it to work.  Give me a few hours, I might have something in the archive.